# How can i track how much bandwidth is used by a streaming video

Tags: iis, video-streaming, bandwidth-measuring

I have a website that has limited streaming for my clients. This has grown beyond the initial intent and has become a bit of an issue with my bandwidth charges.

My question is: on IIS is there a way, and what is it, to track how much actual bandwidth is being consumed by a file per month or any time frame?

So, for example, I know that file 'x.mpg' belongs to Jerry and I want to charge Jerry if he goes over a certain amount of bandwidth for streaming his video how can I see how much bandwidth that file ate up as people streamed it.

The number doesn't have to be exact if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a web log analyzer to get to this kind of information. [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is a particularly popular piece of software for doing this and it works with IIS too:

http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=50526

Comment: Was able to use a web analyzer I fixed up for doing this thanks for the push in the right direction.